# Difference between "rigid area" and "strut" in Box

Tags: java, swing, layout

Could someone please explain the differences between

```
Box.createRigidArea(dimension)
```

and

```
Box.createHorizontalStrut(width)

Box.createVerticalStrut(height)
```

Is "Rigid area" a strut whose both dimensions can be user-specified, or is there more to it?

Comment: ehem ... what about reading the api doc?

Comment: actually, no. I was reading the OpenJDK sources. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tutorial

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

It looks like using struts as a filler may present problems when composing different BoxLayouts meanwhile rigid areas are more flexible since they allow you to specify both dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, a horizontal strut has effectively unlimited maximum height. So, if we put a horizontal strut in a horizontal box inside a vertical box, suddenly the horizontal box becomes taller. So, a horizontal strut also acts like vertical glue, I guess. Which, intuitively, is not what we expect from the idea of a "horizontal strut".